# MUI : disable button conditional

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I want to the disable a button if "numSelected" is 0.

I try :

```
<IconButton
  aria-label="Delete"
  disabled={numSelected < 0 && true}
>
  <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numSelected` will most likely never be less than `0`, but you can check if it's equal to `0` instead.

```
<IconButton aria-label="Delete" disabled={numSelected === 0}>
  <DeleteIcon />
</IconButton>
```